# Unable to run script for creating a new table

Tags: php, pdo, database-connection

I wrote the following script to create a new table in my database

```
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

# DATABASE CONNECTION
$dbname = "test";
$host = "localhost";
$username = "postgres";
$password = "pssw";

try{
    $dbh = new PDO("pgsql:dbname=$dbname; host=$host", $username, $password);
    $dbh->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION ); # Error Handling
    $tbl = 'CREATE TABLE "genes" (
        "id" SERIAL,
        "gene_id" BIGINT NOT NULL,
        "plasmid" VARCHAR(20),
        )';
    $dbh->exec($tbl);
    print("Created New Table.\n");
    }

catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage(); 
}
```

But when I run the script I got the following message "could not find driver". On the internet I found that my version where maybe not up to date or not installed. So I tried it out. Everything is up to date now. And it is still not working. Could there be a mistake in my database connection or is there something else?

Comment: First of all, you have syntax error on variable `$tbl`. You have to remove `,` and close `'` at the end before `);`

Comment: Thanks. In my original script this I doesn't have this error. I didn't show all my columns because it wouldn't be clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have a module called pdo_mysql , check your phpinfo() if it's installed.

Comment: This is the module 'mysqlnd 5.0.12-dev - 20150407 - $Id: 38fea24f2847fa7519001be390c98ae0acafe387 $'

Comment: in your php.ini you need the Postgres driver (usually extension=pgsql.so )